# Change windows 10 local password after logged in with pin

Tags: windows-10, logging, password-recovery

I have windows 10 installed on my pc and I am logging into windows with PIN or fingerprint. And I forgot the password of windows. Windows password is required to run some special commands or run programs.

How can I reset or view the windows password?

As I logged into PC. I searched for many solutions, but I didn't find any solution. Somebody please help me in this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, open command prompt as administrator and run:

```
net user username *
```

Where `username` is your local  user name (Not Microsoft account) Then type new password and confirm it. The local password will be reset.

Comment: By Using this I am getting this error "The password does not meet the password policy requirements. Check the minimum password length, password complexity and password history requirements."  And I am the administrator of the pc and there is no other account exists in pc.